# ERROR ITMS-4088 - Does not have permission to modify the application

Tags: submit, xcode6

Ok, so I am trying to submit an app for a client of ours.

They have invited me to their developer program as 'Admin' and we created all of the certs, provisioning profiles, and distribution profiles.

I am able to select their account when submitting also.

I go to submit the app via XCode 6.0.1 and it gets all the way to authenticating with iTunes Connect, then it throws this error...

ERROR ITMS-4088: "The organization "Company Name" does not have permission to modify the application with the Apple ID "App ID".  Please try again, using an account for an organization with access to this application" at SoftwareAssets

Does anyone know why I am getting this?

I am pretty sure everything is setup correctly.  Help!  Thanks!

Comment: I've just run into this problem as well. I've posted in Apple Developer forums but no answers yet.

Comment: @morgman can you link to the post?

Comment: Sure:  https://devforums.apple.com/thread/249362?tstart=0
As I say in the post I got around this error using an account that was just a member of a single development team.  But previous versions of our app were submitted from my account which is a member of multiple teams... course that was in Xcode 5

Comment: So I actually had to add their Apple ID account to my list of accounts in XCode, then when choosing a dev team during the submission process I had to select theirs.  After that it finished the upload, but I am sure there are ways to accomplish this without using the clients credentials, I will also try @Gonzalo Gallotti's solution below.

Comment: [Xcode Dialog Image](http://cl.ly/image/0U3Z2O3t1D1e/Screen_Shot_2014-10-07_at_10_30_22.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Xcode. Preferences/Accounts.

Make sure you have logged in with your Company Account.
The within your project go to General/Identity/Team and set your Company Team.

This worked for me.

Comment: I've done all this and still get the error. My account is associated with more than one team, but I have the correct one selected in General/Identity/Team. It matches the provisioning profile and code signing ID.

Comment: In Xcode 6.1, you can have multiple Apple IDs.  I added my other one and was able to upload the app by selecting the app from my second Apple ID.

Comment: @tybro0103 I am facing exact same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AdilMalik Yeah... use Application Loader instead of Xcode.

Comment: Instead of Xcode I used the Apple’s Application Loader 3.7 which is very ease to use and make the submission faster. It has been the final answer to my issue. Here's how to generate binary (.IPA) file using organizer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html

Comment: This is not the correct answer, the problem lies in Xcodes handling (or non-handling) of multiple accounts during the app store upload phase. For some reason you can't select this if you have multiple accounts in the Accounts section, and the other answers on this page are correct in that you need to use the Application Loader tool. In my case, this issue just magically started appearing without changing anything, I guess Xcode had just randomly re-sorted the account list and took another account this time..

Answer (score 37):

This one worked for me:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1056570#1056570

Using the ITC Credentials with the Application Loader

Comment: Worked for me! To me this really looks like an XCode bug, and I believe it stems from the fact that iTunes Connect and the rest of the developer program use separate systems of accounts. XCode is trying to user the developer program account, while iTunes Connect is looking for the iTunes Connect account. Since XCode doesn't allow you to force it to use a particular iTunes Connect account, you have to use Application Loader in order to explicitly log in and use an iTunes Connect account.

Comment: This worked for me. My account is associated with multiple teams, and seems XCode has an issue and keeps picking up the wrong team. Using Application Loader, worked, after signing in with the customer's account. An XCode bug it seems.

Comment: I would agree.  This does look like a Xcode bug.  Same problem and solution here.

Comment: Also getting the same error from application loader. My account is a member of multiple organizations, and it seems it's not selecting the correct one

Comment: Be aware that even in Application Loader you have to be logged in with the proper Itunes Connect account. A lot of headache until I realized that.

Comment: This worked for me but oddly I had to use a different account still. My account is a member of multiple organizations and when submitting it selects the top one every time (Which is my personal) it did work on the other account that didn't have a personal attached.

Answer (score 32):

SOLVED: Product->Archive->Export->Save for iOS App Store. Close Organizer and go to Xcode->Xcode(Menu)->Open Developer Tool->Application Loader, then sign in with your iTunes connect account and choose ipa.

Comment: Works like a charm. I ran into this problem since I got one "big" account linked with about 20 customer developer.apple.com but no itunesconnect.apple.com accounts. It seems like Xcode is getting confused when those linked accounts are not compatible with itunesconnect.apple.com since we splitted them to other email addresses.

Comment: @Blauesocke same. I tried to export by choosing developer team and it sent me error, since i tried iTunes connect account

Answer (score 5):

In our case, we had access to the [Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/) and [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) under different users, as well as having access to multiple Developer/iTC programs under multiple logins.

When submitting from Xcode, the IDE was attempting to use the incorrect combinations of credentials.

We worked around the issue by archiving the build with the correct provisioning profile and code signing identity, then exporting the IPA and using Application Loader to upload:

1. Choose the correct Code Signing Identity: `Project > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity > Distribution App Store`
2. Choose the correct Provisioning Profile: `Project > Code Signing > Provisioning Profile > Distribution App Store`
3. Archive: `Product > Archive`
4. In the Organizer, choose to Export your newly-archived project, choosing `Save for Ad Hoc Development`
5. Choose the correct Development team
6. Export the `.ipa` file
7. Open `Application Loader` and authenticate with the appropriate **iTunes Connect** account
8. Upload the new version

Answer (score 3):

I had to be **added to iTunes Connect as an admin** - even though my distribution certificate was good and I had a valid production provisioning profile, I still needed to be added to iTunes connect. Hope this helps anyone who have done all of the above and still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to wait a few minutes.

I had only just created the app on App Store Connect, so I guess there was some internal processing going on preventing me from uploading it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the bundle identifier in Xcode did not match the bundle identifier associated with my app in Itunes Connect.

To check the bundle ID in Xcode, go to "General" then "Bundle Identifier".

To check the bundle ID in Itunes Connect. Navigate to your app, then "More", "About this App" then "Bundle Identifier".

These two Bundle Identifiers HAVE to match or else you will get this error when submitting.